# How to add formik handleChange, handleBlur, etc into the component

Tags: react-native, formik

I am using react-native. How can I move this part of the code below, into the AppForm component file? And everything still work.

```
 {({
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit,
          values,
          errors,
          isValid,
                }) => (
```

**AppForm component**

```
 <Formik
    initialValues={initialValues}
    onSubmit={onSubmit}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
    style={[style, styles.form]}>
    {children}
 </Formik>
```

**AppForm component being used**

```
<AppForm
     validationSchema={loginValidationSchema}
     initialValues={{email: '', password: ''}}
     onSubmit={(values: {email: string; password: string}) => {
       login(values.email, values.password);
     }}>
      {({
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit,
          values,
          errors,
          isValid,
                }) => (
                  <View>
                    <AppInputField
                      style={{
                        backgroundColor: 'white',
                      }}
                      placeholder="Email Address"
                      onChange={handleChange('email')}
                      onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
           ..........
```

I want to remove the code from this file ^ and move it into the AppForm component. Not sure how that will work...